# No jqPlot-plugin is working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, plugins, jqplot

I am using jqPlot to draw some simple line charts and it works great in Chrome. But in every version of IE (including 9) the jqPlot-plugins are not working. I've tried the pointLabels, dateAxisRenderer and highlighter plugin but they don't have any effect.

My code is pretty much the same as in the examples on the jqPlot site. The only difference I am aware of is that I create the div-element placeholder for the chart dynamically via JavaScript.

That's the code I use to create the chart:

```
 scurve_chart = $.jqplot('cv', [line1], {
            title: 'distribute costs',
            seriesDefaults: { 
                showMarker:false,
                pointLabels: { show: true, location: 's', ypadding: 3 }
            },
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    min: 0.5,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%.0f'
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    max: Math.round(max_value_to_dist * 1.10),
                    min: 0,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%.0f'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I use the latest version of jqplot and jquery-1.4.1

**//update: Solution**

The problem was that I included all plugin-files directly from the jqplot homepage. For example:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqplot.com/src/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>`

It seems like IE does not like it that way.

Comment: If below answer doesnt help, can you also show the code you use to create the DIV placeholder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You omitted to show your includes in the example code you provide - does it draw anything at all in IE or it draws the basic line graph but doesnt use the renderers ?

For IE, you need to include the following line (ensuring the path to excanvas.js is pointed to the same directory that contains your jqplot.js)

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.js">
            </script><![endif]-->
```

Also for each plugin, there is another include to be added e.g. for the barrenderer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js">
</script>
```

again with the correct path specified to the .js file

If you have the paths specified, check they are listed before the  tag containing $(document).ready(function() and ensure any .css files are loaded right at the start.

Comment: I found the problem (see updated question). Since your hint that something might be wrong with the script-tags was pretty good - I think your answer deserves to be accepted.

Comment: Everyone loves microsoft right ? - they make the life of a web developer so much easier ... lol